# Deployment Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, deployment, next.js

As already mentioned, we cannot use dynamic routes with next export. For example, I have /post/:id, where the identifier cannot be predefined. I heard about npm run start, but I don’t know how to deploy in this way. I use Caddy instead of NGINX. The main problem is how to build next.js SSR. When I do SPA I setup NGINX in Dockerfile and copy out/ folder to /usr/share/nginx/html. But in SSR I need to start node.js server and here I have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is closed, my problem was that I didn't copy `src/` folder.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY src/ ./src/
COPY public/ ./public/

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Hi, Can you post your full config file for caddy and ssr nextjs on production. I am facing the similer issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66451934/deploying-dynamic-nextjs-nodejs-application-inside-docker-using-caddy-server