# Deploying dynamic Nextjs + Nodejs application inside docker using caddy server

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, caddy

I am currently developing a simple portfolio app and my app structure is like this.
Nextjs/client,
Nodejs/server,
Mongodb/db

Nextjs is hosted locally on port 3001, Nodejs app on 5000. Whenever nextjs needs to fetch any api it calls nodejs application. All the things are configured inside docker. I am very new to deploying nextjs application and have recently used caddy server which has automatic https.
I am able to deploy the nextjs application statically using commands

```
next build
next export
```

The statically exported file called index.html inside out directory of nextjs application is pointed to caddy server on port 80 and 443. Statically exported app doesn't support api routes which I recently came to know. I tried `next build and next start` command to generate a dynamic production build inside .next directory. The main problem is How do I point my dynamically generated nextjs application in caddy configuration inside docker container. My present caddy configuration looks like

```
www.example.com:443 {
 tls xyz@email.com
 root * /srv
 route {
   reverse_proxy /api* api-server:5000
   try_files {path} {path}/ /index.html
   file_server
   }
}
```

I am looking for hints especially related to proxy server.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the **api url** in your frontend looks like this `http://localhost:5000` (based on your youtube comment [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DftsReyhz2Q&t=5020s)) which won't work if you're accessing your dockerized app from a remote computer (in this case your computer, since I'm assuming your app is hosted). Try changing it to `https://www.example.com:5000` and rebuild your image.